# converting pdf to png and issues rendering bold font

Tags: ghostscript, imagick

I ran into an issue when converting pdfs to pngs.

Locally, everything works fine. On a remote server however (same ghostscript and imagick version), we run into issues with bold fonts (see attached examples).

The only difference are that I have way more fonts available locally than on the server. Could this be the issue here?

Attached screenshots: 1 (screenshot from original pdf and how it looks when converting locally, they are the same), 2 (converted on the server).
[image]

[image]

Comment: Nobody is going to be able to say much without seeing the PDF file in question. Clearly the two are using different fonts (look at the upper part of the lower case 'f' for example) , which implies the PDF file does not contain the font it requests. You should look at the back channel output for each to try and determine which fonts are being used in each case. You also haven't stated which version of Ghostscript you are using. At a guess I'd say the text is 'fake bold', it is filled and then the outline is stroked with a wide line to make it bolder. Are you using *AlphaBits ?

Comment: @KenS I sadly cant post the pdf as it contains sensitive data and we get it from a customer. we arent using alphaBits. the mention of the different f is a good point, I didnt see that

Comment: Just checked back. The installed version on the server is 9.25, locally i have 10.01.2, will have to get that corrected

Comment: Sounds like it may be a long corrected bug, 9.25 is relatively old (5 years old) and has a number of well known security vulnerabilities, you should upgrade your server to 10 10.02.0 (which has just been released), urgently I would say, if you accept jobs from the outside.